# Is there a way to speed up concatenation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, concatenation

I want to concatenate along the third dimension

```
z = cat(3,A,B,C);
```

Many many times.  I if I was doing that along the second dimension then

```
z = [A,B,C];
```

Would be faster than

```
z = cat(2,A,B,C);
```

Can a similar thing be done along the third dimension or is there any other way to speed this up?

Comment: I've never looked at it before, how are you evaluating the speed difference between `cat` and `[]`. As an aside, a better starting point may be to address why you need repeated concatenation calls in the first place.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I show no time difference at all with the [provided code snippet](https://gist.github.com/sco1/7dabf3c845a30711c71e) in R2015b.

Comment: @excaza It really is faster, try [this](http://i.imgur.com/zJQoHd9.png) yourself, I evaluate it through time profiler. I can't explain here why do I need it, it's bit complicated though if want to know we could talk through mail or facebook

Comment: @excaza my version is 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)

Comment: Profiling with R2014a reproduces the behavior you experience with R2015a. Seems like R2015b's new execution engine brought the speed of `cat` in line with `[]`. So my totally unhelpful first suggestion would be to update MATLAB ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are some indexing options to get a slightly better performance than `cat(3,...)`.

Both solutions use `U(30,30,3)=0;` instead of `zeros(30,30,3)` to preallocate, but it is unsave as it will result in a subscript dimension missmatch when U is already a variable of a larger size.

The first option is to assign the different slices individually.

```
%fast but unsafe preallocation
U(30,30,3)=0;
%robust alternative:
%U=zeros(30,30,3)
U(:,:,3)=C;
U(:,:,1)=A;
U(:,:,2)=B;
```

The second option is to use linear indexing. For `z1 = cat(3,A,B,C);` and `z2=[A;B;C]` it is true that `z1(:)==z2(:)`

```
%fast but unsafe preallocation
U(30,30,3)=0;
%robust alternative:
%U=zeros(30,30,3)
U(:)=[A,B,C];
```

I benchmarked the solutions, comparing it to `cat(3,A,B,C)` and `[A,B,C]`. The linear indexing solution is only slightly slower than `[A,B,C]`.

```
0.392289 s for 2D CAT
0.476525 s for Assign slices
0.588346 s for cat(3...)
0.392703 s for linear indexing
```

Code for benchmarking:

```
N=30;
A=randn(N,N);
B=randn(N,N);
C=randn(N,N);
T=containers.Map;
cycles=10^5;
tic;
for i=1:cycles
    W=[A;B;C];
    X=W+1;
end
T('2D CAT')=toc;
tic;
for i=1:cycles
    W=cat(3,A,B,C);
    X=W+1;
end
T('cat(3...)')=toc;
U=zeros(N,N,3);
tic;
for i=1:cycles
    U(N,N,3)=0;
    U(:,:,3)=C;
    U(:,:,1)=A;
    U(:,:,2)=B;
    V=U+1;
end
T('Assign slices')=toc;
tic;
for i=1:cycles
    U(N,N,3)=0;
    U(:)=[A,B,C];
    V=U+1;
end
T('linear indexing')=toc;


for X=T.keys
    fprintf('%f s for %s\n',T(X{1}),X{1})
end
```

Comment: I compared preallocation both ways earlier today and `U = zeros(30,30,3)` turned out to be faster than `U(30,30,3) = 0`. And I checked now `cat()` is bit faster in my version of the Matlab than the methods you provided... But thanks anyways!

Comment: Again different performance on different Matlab versions, with Matlab 2013a my solution was faster.