# Slow NaN relational comparisons in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

It appears that doing numerical relational operations (greater than, less than) on NaNs is 10 times slower than on non-NaNs in **MATLAB R2013a (ver 8.1)**.

```
>> a = rand(10000);
>> b = NaN(size(a));

>> tic; a>0; toc
Elapsed time is 0.083838 seconds.

>> tic; b>0; toc
Elapsed time is 0.991742 seconds.
```

Some experimentation shows the time taken scales with the proporation of NaNs in the array, such that an array of all NaNs takes longest and all non-NaNs is quickest. Infs are as quick as non-NaNs.

I'm doing comparisons on arrays with large numbers of NaNs. To hack around this slow down, I'm replacing NaNs in my arrays with Infs (e.g. `-Inf` if I were doing b>0). This helps, but the replacement itself is slow. Indeed it's only because I'm doing many such comparisons on the same array that the one-off replacement helps overall.

So my question is, does anyone have any better ideas for comparing against lots of NaNs?

Comment: which Matlab version?  for me R2015b on win 64 -> the times are the same!

Comment: @matlabgui: Really?! Gah, I'm on 2013a. Should have mentioned that (will edit Q)!

Comment: @matlabgui It's worth nothing that R2015b contains a fairly significant [execution engine upgrade](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#zmw57dd0e3251). I've seen it come up with benchmarking [fairly recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761451/).

Comment: R2015a takes 8.5 times longer for the `NaN` one.

Comment: I tried it on 2009a and get                                                                     Elapsed time is 0.077833 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.073732 seconds.

Comment: Why are you doing computations with NaN?!

Comment: and on 2014b I get: Elapsed time is 0.048310 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.054568 seconds. Not sure why on 2015 and 2013 it should take longer and not on 2009 and 2014, perhaps I can find a computer here with 2015b or 2013a on it to crosscheck

Comment: I can also confirm that R2010a is also ~10 times slower with NaNs....

Comment: Tested on Matlab 2011b 64bit. Times are almost the same. Are you using a 64 bit version?

Comment: On Matlab 2014a 64bit times are almost the same. Very strange...

Comment: On 2015a, Win64 - Nans are even faster:
>> tic; a>0; toc
Elapsed time is 0.128266 seconds.
>> tic; b>0; toc
Elapsed time is 0.104979 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Matlab R2014a, and the time is the same. However, I suggest doing the following to see if it works:
tic; c = isnan(b) ; toc;

This allows to transform the matrix of NaN to a  matrix of logical, where "true" means it is a NaN. The new matrix will be faster than the old one, and you would simply have to redefine your comparison. For example, if you have a matrix "A" containing numbers and NaN, and you want to find numbers greater than 0, you would have:

```
A = myMatrix;

% The inverse sign "~" means that "true" is a number, while "false" is a nan
B = ~isnan(A);  

% Greater than 0 for non-nan
C = B & A>0
```

Comment: Are you saying this is quicker? Surely this will be slower still. The last line will do the same full comparison on all elements of A and then AND it with B?

Comment: Yes it will be slower, but I suspect it to be faster than what you are doing if you have a lot of NaN. The use of isnan takes approximately the same time as the use of a logical operator on a double matrix.

The last line will make 2 comparisons, which means it will take twice the time of a normal comparison.

Therefore, I gave you a code that is slower, but ~2-4 times slower for a full NaN matrix, which is better than your code which is 12 times slower.
It will then be faster only if you have a majority of NaN.

But it is only speculation. My PC gives the same toc time when running your code.